# Infrastructure monitoring using netdata - No package autogen available. libmnl-devel lz4-devel python3-pymongo

Tags: linux, package, monitoring, yum, netdata

**RedHat** Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)

Trying to install latest [netdata](https://www.netdata.cloud/) monitoring tool on my EC2 machine.

Ran the following command:

```
bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh)   --disable-telemetry
```

Got the following errors.

```
$ bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh)
System            : Linux
Operating System  : GNU/Linux
Machine           : x86_64
BASH major version:
 --- Fetching script to detect required packages... ---
[/tmp/netdata-kickstart-jvcHm3]$ curl -sSL --connect-timeout 10 --retry 3 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/netdata/netdata/master/packaging/installer/install-required-packages.sh  OK

 --- Running downloaded script to detect required packages... ---
[/tmp/netdata-kickstart-jvcHm3]$ sudo /usr/bin/bash /tmp/netdata-kickstart-jvcHm3/install-required-packages.sh netdata Loading /etc/os-release ...
/tmp/netdata-kickstart-jvcHm3/install-required-packages.sh: line 1050: validate_tree_rhel: command not found

/etc/os-release information:
NAME            : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
VERSION         : 7.7 (Maipo)
ID              : rhel
ID_LIKE         : fedora
VERSION_ID      : 7.7

We detected these:
Distribution    : rhel
Version         : 7.7
Codename        : 7.7 (Maipo)
Package Manager : install_yum
Packages Tree   : rhel
Detection Method: /etc/os-release
Default Python v: 2 (will install python3 too)

Searching for distro_sdk ...
Searching for autoconf_archive ...
WARNING
package autoconf-archive is not available in this system.
You may try to install without it.

Searching for autogen ...
 > Checking if package 'autogen' is installed...
Searching for libz_dev ...
 > Checking if package 'zlib-devel' is installed...
Searching for libuuid_dev ...
 > Checking if package 'libuuid-devel' is installed...
Searching for libmnl_dev ...
 > Checking if package 'libmnl-devel' is installed...
Searching for libuv ...
 > Checking if package 'libuv-devel' is installed...
Searching for lz4 ...
 > Checking if package 'lz4-devel' is installed...
Searching for openssl ...
 > Checking if package 'openssl-devel' is installed...
Searching for judy ...
 > Checking if package 'Judy-devel' is installed...
Searching for python3_pymongo ...
 > Checking if package 'python3-pymongo' is installed...

The following command will be run:

 >> IMPORTANT <<
    Please make sure your system is up to date
    by running:   yum update

yum install autogen libmnl-devel lz4-devel python3-pymongo


Press ENTER to run it >
yum install autogen libmnl-devel lz4-devel python3-pymongo
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No package autogen available.
No package libmnl-devel available.
No package lz4-devel available.
No package python3-pymongo available.
Error: Nothing to do



We are very sorry!

Installation of required packages failed.

What to do now:

  1. Make sure your system is updated.
     Most of the times, updating your system will resolve the issue.

  2. If the error message is about a specific package, try removing
     that package from the command and run it again.
     Depending on the broken package, you may be able to continue.

  3. Let us know. We may be able to help.
     Open a github issue with the above log, at:

           https://github.com/firehol/netdata/issues


 FAILED

 WARNING  It failed to install all the required packages, but installation might still be possible.

Press ENTER to attempt netdata installation > ^C
```

I checked, yum.repos.d file (showing just `epel-testing` entry, enabled=0, I changed it to 1), still getting the above error:

```
 [epel-testing]
 name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - $basearch
 #baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/7/$basearch
 metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=testing-epel7&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
 failovermethod=priority
 enabled=1
 gpgcheck=1
 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
```

Do I need to look into some other repo config file or change something else? Installing other yum modules, pip installs etc work fine.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of pressing `^C`, just press keyboard **ENTER** key and installation will complete successfully.

```
 ...
 ......
 OK

Setting netdata.tarball.checksum to 'new_installation'

The following non-fatal errors were encountered during the installation process:

* Failed to build JSON-C. Netdata Cloud support will be disabled.

 --- We are done! ---

  ^
  |.-.   .-.   .-.   .-.   .-.   .  netdata                          .-.   .-
  |   '-'   '-'   '-'   '-'   '-'   is installed and running now!  -'   '-'
  +----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--->

  enjoy real-time performance and health monitoring...

 OK

[ec2-user@elk-stack dump]$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the official installation method `bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh)` and not the packages that are vendored by linux distributions, as they don't contain all the features that Netdata currently has.

I would advise you to uninstall and install it using our script. If you have any further questions, I would be happy to answer :)